# Debian installation can't find Ethernet driver

Tags: drivers, debian

I'm trying to install Debian 6.0.7 to my Sony Vaio VPCCA3S1E laptop from USB flash disk via netinst.   The installer can't find the driver for my Ethernet card so it can't download the installation files. I need to install it from a 4GB USB flash drive, that's why I've chosen netinst version. I've tried to Google some help but i didn't find anything.

I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your network card has a proprietary firmware that is not shipped on the debian .iso for legal reasons.

What error message is exactly the setup giving you?

You should use another machine that has network connection to download the required file, so that the setup can install it and you can go forward.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, but I've already solved this problem by downloading Debian Wheezy instead of Squeezy. With Wheezy there was no problem during installation :)